# Will node js compile javascript code which is saved in other extensions?

Tags: javascript, node.js

so, today when i'm going to save my javascript code, i've saved it with other extension, and the code is compiled successfully

```
//server.mp3


var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
})
app.listen(3000, function () {
console.log("Listening at 3000")
});
```

when i said :

```
 node server.mp3
```

my server is running on port 3000...
how it is possible?

Comment: My main question is why?

Comment: Why would it *not* work?!

Comment: This is dark magic

Comment: Just FYI, the JavaScript engine Node.js uses (Google's V8) often doesn't compile code (and often it does). One-time setup code is usually just interpreted. Code used repeatedly will get compiled and aggressively optimized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node.js doesn't do different things depending on what type of file you open with it. It therefore doesn't try to determine what type of file you have given it based on the file extension. It just tries to execute it as JS.

Comment: if we take java it will work only with .java extension, how can node can compile any other extension?

Comment: @RamachandraReddy node.js does not examine the file extension, what it cares about is running every line of instructions in the file. The filename just tells node which particular file to run it's content